# How can i wait for some text without stopping the execution of the test?

Tags: vue.js, webdriver-io, end-to-end, codeceptjs

I am doing some end-to-end test with *CodeceptJS* and *WebdriverIO* helper and I would like to wait an error message in my Vue.js SPA. 
I want to know if there is a way to wait for a text asynchronously during the runtime of the test. I don't want to use a `wait()` because this would increase the duration of my test, instead I would like that, during the runtime of the test it fails the test if it sees some "Error" text for example.
Like the `dontSee()` function but in the background of my test, I can't explain it very well.

Comment: Could you perhaps post some code illustrating what you have tried so far? It sounds to me as though this is a situation where you want to use a Promise.

Answer (score 1):

For example the validate error doesn't appear immediatly, so I need to wait if I see that label in the page. I don't want to stop my tests for ten second, I just would like something like a "Watcher" for that label for some seconds.

```
I.click('#btnSave');
//I.wait(10);
I.dontSee('Error validate');
I.waitForText('Save successful', 5);
```

The `waitForText()` is perfect for the opposite need. There isn't a function like `waitForTextToFail()`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question fully, but I think you might be looking for something like this:  http://webdriver.io/api/utility/waitForVisible.html

You will notice that it has a parameter called `reverse` which will let you assert for the opposite.

It might look something like this: `browser.waitForVisible('#elem', 3000, true);`

The `reverse` flag also works for the `waitForText` method.

Comment: I didn't know this `reverse` parameter, it would be perfect for my intent. Unfortunately codecept's parameters are different and there isn't this functionality.

Comment: If that is the case, look here:  https://codecept.io/acceptance/#waiting   It looks like you have access to something called `I.dontSeeElement()`